# Using $(filter) in GNU makefiles static pattern rules

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have this GNU makefile:

```
SOURCE = source1/a source2/b source3/c
BUILD  = build/a build/b build/c
BASE   = build/

$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: %
    install $< $@
```

So basically I have files in the directories *source1*, *source2* and *source3*, which I want to regardlessly put into the *build* directory.

I want to accomplish this with a single static pattern rule. My naïve approach would be this:

```
$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: $(filter *%, $(SOURCE))
    install $< $@
```

This doesn't work. I know that filters are also denoted with percentage signs.

```
$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: $(wildcard */$(notdir %))
    install $< $@
```

This doesn't work either. But even if, this would still be non-satisfactory, as I might want to `touch` a new file source1/b, which would mess everything up.

**How can I use the `$(filter)` function in GNU makefile static pattern rules? Or is there another approach to do accomplish this?**

The hierarchy now looks like this:

```
source1/
        a
source2/
        b
source3/
        c
build/
```

I want it to look like this:

```
source1/
        a
source2/
        b
source3/
        c
build/
        a
        b
        c
```

Comment: If you have `source1/b` and `source2/b`, then what do you want to put into `build/`?

Comment: I want to put `a`, `b` and `c` into `build`.

Comment: *Which* `b` do you want to put into `build/`? You say that you might wish to introduce `source/b` in addition to `source2/b`, but you don't say what you want Make to do in that case.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I misread your answer! I'd want to put `source2/b` into build, because it is in the `$(SOURCE)` variable. I think this problem can't be appropriately solved in make, so I would do that outside of make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [the VPATH variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search):

```
SOURCE = source1/a source2/b source3/c
BUILD  = build/a build/b build/c
BASE   = build/

VPATH = source1 source2 source3

$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: %
    install $< $@
```

Or:

```
SOURCE = source1/a source2/b source3/c
BASE   = build/
BUILD  = $(addprefix $(BASE), $(notdir $(SOURCE)))

VPATH = $(dir $(SOURCE))

$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: %
    install $< $@
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading a thousand Stackoverflow questions and the GNU make tutorial for hours, I finally got it working:

```
SOURCE = source1/a source2/b source3/c
TEST   = a b c
BUILD  = build/a build/b build/c
BASE   = build/
PERCENT = %

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(BUILD): $(BASE)%: $$(filter $$(PERCENT)/$$*,$$(SOURCE))
    install $< $@
```

It's kinda hacky, but I'm happy with it. If anybody got any better idea, please let me know.